# Understanding HQL queries on collection objects

Tags: collections, hql

This is similar to a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425765/cross-fetch-created-on-bi-directional-one-to-many-jpa-hibernate-query). The answers to that question partially solved my issue, but I'm still having some issues in trying to perform the kind of search I specified there; furthermore, I'm simply having trouble understanding how Hibernate chooses what to return in different scenarios.

Here's my mapping:

```
Client {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
}

Group {
    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Client client = new Client();

    private String name;  
    private String state; //two char state code
    private String extId; //unique identifier; candidate key, but not the @Id.
}
```

Queries by name are inline (e.g., like with wildcards on both ends of the param); state and extId are by equality.

The following query returns a single client, with only the matching group attached, even if other groups are associated to the client (note again that extId will only return one group):

```
select distinct client from Client as client
inner join client.groups as grp
where grp.extId = :extId
```

---

This query returns a single client, but with **all** associated groups attached, regardless of whether the group's state code matches the criteria:

```
select distinct client from Client as client
inner join client.groups as grp
where grp.state= :state
```

---

Finally, this query returns a separate copy of the client **for each matched group**, and each copy contains all of its associated groups, regardless of whether the group's name matches the criteria:

```
select distinct client from Client as client
inner join client.groups as grp
where grp.name like :name
```

I'm new to Hibernate, and I'm finding it immensely frustrating that I'm unable to predict what is going to be returned from a given query. All three queries are nearly identical, except for some small changes in the WHERE clause, yet I get radically different results for each. I'd spent time reviewing the documentation, but I'm missing wherever this behavior is explained. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Finally, what I really need to do is to return `Client`s when querying by `Group`, and have the client *only* contain the `Group`s which match the search criteria. Is there a single-shot way I can construct an HQL query to do so, or will I have to do multiple queries and build my objects up in code?

Thanks.

Comment: That's absolutely not what I observe. Are you sure the groups collection is lazy-loaded? Are you sure every query has a distinct, and doesn't have a fetch clause? Those three queries, with alazy-loaded collection, have exactly the same behavior in my tests, as expected.

Comment: Well, it's not annotated for eager loading, and I'm not doing a fetch join, so I don't know why or how it would be eagerly loaded. It *used* to be though, so I'll try cleaning the build in Eclipse. If that's it, I'm going to scream and go firebombing, not necessarily in that order. FWIW, what behavior are you seeing? You said they're all the same for you, but what is it?

Comment: Each query loads distinct entities, and all the elements of the collection are present when loaded.

Comment: Looks like it might be a problem with the test harness. I repointed the test at existing data (ugh) instead of data set up in the harness and I'm now getting the same results as you described. Thanks for testing it independently. You wouldn't have any suggestions for my last question, would you? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is twofold. One, there was a problem with the test harness, which was (sensibly) using transaction rollback to create test instances without leaving artifacts in the database. This was the source of my odd responses in the queries.

I managed to return just the values I wanted in the collections by simply changing to an outer fetch join.